# Power BI/DAX using parameters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm a bit new to the DAX/Power BI, so i dont have broad understanding of it.

I have table 'Sales' as follows:

```
ItemID     SalesValue     Amount     actionSales        Date
   1          0.5           2             0          2018-02-18
   1          0.3           5             1          2018-02-18
   1          0.5           6             0          2018-02-19
```

-I left out some fileds as description, brand, etc...

-actionSales field is a bit, that represent if sold item was on a discount.

I have made few measures that have total salesValue, total salesValueOnActionSales, percentOfActionSales, etc...

Within visuals in Power BI I can filter values if they are greater or lower then some value.

Then i figured that it would be nice to show only items that have share of action sales greater then 'parameter' (Parametr is a whole number, and it is in visual with a slider) that I made on a report.

After some time, I'm no closer to a solution. Can this be made? if it can, can someone please point me to a direction on how to do this or share some insights on the matter.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the 'What If' parameter in PowerBI. In short: you define a parameter, connect it to a slicer and use the parameter in a measure.

[Link to MSDN Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/power-bi/desktop-what-if)

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your answer or I was not clear enough in a question. I do not want to re/calculate measure. I want my visual to filter data based on filter. i.e. Parameter is from 0-100, and on visual i want to show only data that have salesValueOnActionSales/TotalSalesValue > parameter. As in question, if parameter is 30, the item 1 will be shown, but if parameter is 40, it will be filtered out.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the things you can do with it. Since it's jsut a parameter, which you can use in any measure, you can be as creative as you want. You can multiple the measure by the parameter, or you can filter the measure. For example, to filter out any item with sales < parameter.

Comment: I've created a quick sample for you. I didn't correct the totals: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ia7ffsic9ogjf6u/DAX_27-3-2018.pbix?dl=0

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example TJ_, I've been trying to achieve something like this and couldn't find out how to make it work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not add the actionSales column to a slicer and select Greater than or equal to from the options?

If this doesn't work let me know and I have another solution that might do it.

Comment: well, i can allways add manualy a number in visualisation only to show greater or lesser then. But i wanna get some user exp. so i can change the value that is greater then or less then on the go. So that report consumers can do that by themself without editing report.